# Qt5 - right way to change content

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

I'm new to Qt development and I'm facing a small problem.

At the start of my program,  I'm showing a big window with two buttons, and I want those buttons to bring a new content into the window  when I click on it, like a "next" button on some installers.

What I was doing for this is that I created another class,  like SecondWindow, which inherited `QWidget`, and I loaded it when button was clicked,  but even though it can work,  I can tell it's not "the right thing to do" and I would like to know what that would be.

And also,  if you happen to know a good book to learn all this,  I would be quite happy about it.

PS: I'm not using Qt quick,  but I'm not against the idea.

Comment: how do you *load* your second window? do you mean that you instantiated it and called `show()`?

Comment: No, I mean I used this.set something, I don't remember exactly, I won't have my computer until Wednesday. SetCentralWidget maybe? Not sure exactly. Problem is I so had to instantiate my second window in my first one.

Comment: what do you mean by *instantiating your second window in the first one*? Do you mean that your SecondWindow showed up in its own window, while you wanted it to be shown inside your window?

Comment: No,  I mean inside my mainwindow class,  I created a secondwindow element,  which I later called to change the content displayed by my window. Is this clearer?

Comment: If you don't need the first content again, then replacing that centralWidget with a new one sounds fine to me

Comment: I've seen people talking about stackedWidget,  or something like this,  do you think this would be too big for my needs?